# if..else statement in Google Distance Matrix results

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Distance Matrix API to calculate the driving distance + time from one point to another.

I would like to add if..elseif..else statements to the result of the distance search to vary the answers according to how big the distances (e.g. < or > 10 km) are but I'm a newbie to JS and can't seem to figure out where to stick the statements into my code. Any tips?

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
   function calculateDistance(origin, destination) {
      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, callback);
    }

    function callback(response, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        $('#result').html(err);
      } else {
        var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
        var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
        if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
          $('#result').html("We can't seem to find "
                            + origin + ". Are you sure you entered a valid postcode and place?");
        } else {
          var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
          var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
          var distance_value = distance.value;
          var distance_text = distance.text;
          var duration_value = duration.value;
          var duration_text = duration.text;
          var kilometer = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
          $('#result').html("It is " + kilometer + " kilometer from " + origin + " to " + destination + " and it takes " + duration_text + " to drive.");
        }
      }
    }

    $('#distance_form').submit(function(e){
        event.preventDefault();
        var origin = $('#origin').val();
        var destination = $('#destination').val();
        var distance_text = calculateDistance(origin, destination);
    });

  });
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There are if/else statements in the posted code, do they not work?  What did you try that didn't work?  Did you get any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for you reply. I'm trying to accomplish different answers for different ranges of driving distance. Right now it's only showing one answer for all distances ("It is " + kilometer + " kilometer from " + origin + " to " + destination + " and it takes " + duration_text + " to drive."), but I would like to have different answers if e.g. the distance is more and if it's less than 10 km.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have the conditional logic in your `callback` function like this:

```
function callback(response, status) {
  if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    $('#result').html(err);
    return;
  }
  if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status !== "OK") {
    $('#result').html("We can't seem to find " + origin + ". Are you sure you entered a valid postcode and place?");
    return;
  }
  var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
  var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
  var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
  var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
  var distance_value = distance.value;
  var distance_text = distance.text;
  var duration_value = duration.value;
  var duration_text = duration.text;
  var kilometer = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);

  if (distance_value > 10000) {
    $('#result').html('Distance is greater than 10km');
  } else {
    $('#result').html('Distance is less than 10km');
  }
}
```

The response validation is done at the beginning of the function and if the request does not return the desired status, you `return` early and stop the execution of the function. Once these validation statements are out of the way, you can extract all the necessary data from the response and then perform your conditional statements based on any of the values you extracted.

In my example, this is what that looks like:

```
if (distance_value > 10000) {
  $('#result').html('Distance is greater than 10km');
} else {
  $('#result').html('Distance is less than 10km');
}
```

I check to see if the distance value is greater than 10000m (10km) and display a different result based on that.

[Here is a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zuhoxag/12/edit?html,js,output) with a working example.

Comment: @lavor Thank you so much, this helped me a lot! Very kind of you to help.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. Good luck with your project! 

Comment: Thank you @lavor :)